# Asp.net Web Api authorization from Android client

Tags: android, security, authorization, google-plus, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Android application which authenticates the user with **Google+ sign-in**. Now I would like to communicate with my web api to store and get data. What is the most easy way to implement authorization on my web api?

Before implementing  google+ sign-in, users had to register with a username and password and I used basic authentication to authorize users with my server.

**Currently (planning on)using:**

- Client side authentication with google+
- Asp.net web api (no authorization for google+ sign in yet)
- SSL

If anyone could make this process clear and maybe with some examples or webpages to find the information I need that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google+ documentation](https://developers.google.com/+) includes a full explanation of the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/) and its capabilities, which you can use to see what is available for your web implementation. Many of these methods include code snippets for .NET, such as the [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) API call.

There is also a [C#/.NET quick-start](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp) that you can use to see how Google+ Sign-In works at a glance.

Comment: The PhotoHunt .NET sample: https://developers.google.com/plus/photohunt/csharp shows authentication and authorization against an Android client and web/mobile integration in ASP.NET.

Comment: Found this documentation already but will look in to the Photohunt which hopefully make things more clear.